# How to stop vagrant from having to re-download the image on every "vagrant up" on Windows?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows, vvv-wordpress

When I run `vagrant up` on Windows the first time, I expect it to download then cache the box.  But if I run `vagrant halt` followed by `vagrant up` I end up having to wait 15 minutes for the machine to be downloaded and re-assembled; When I ran `vagrant box list`, it states that the base box for it is listed there, so what else do I have to do to use the cache?

```
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/vers
ions/20150902.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
    default: Progress: 94% (Rate: 301k/s, Estimated time remaining: 0:01:20))
```

I remember reading [somewhere in the documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html) that there's a `config.vm.box_check_update` that will cause it to check for updated versions of the current box on every `vagrant up` but I don't see it listed in the `Vagrantfile` for [wordpress-vvv](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV).

Comment: please show your Vagrantfile, maybe something wrong in there

Comment: It looks that after you fully provision your machine `vagrant up` should be [quick](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV#what-did-that-do) as it does not do any provisioning. Also `config.vm.box_check_update` does not cause your problem as it **only** inform about new box version it does **not** update the box automatically for this you need to issue manually `vagrant box update`. So if you see _ubuntu/trusty64_ in your base box list the only reason why this is taking so long is that the machine is being re-created check it's status with `vagrant status` before you do `up`.

Comment: I did try to reproduce your problem with no luck. My vagrant version is 1.7.2, which one you are using? The one thing you can do though to stop re-download is: download _ubuntu/trusty64_ base box [click](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20150902.0.1/providers/virtualbox.box). Place it somewhere in your file system. Then add its location to your Vagrantfile `config.vm.box_url = "file://C:/Path/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"`. This will make Vagrant to take the base box from file location rather than hashicorp repo. This is for VBox VM provider.

Comment: 5 years later, I am facing the same issue. Did anyone ever find a solution to this?